# How to hide deleted files from GitHub for windows

Tags: windows, github, github-for-windows

I have cloned a repository in GitHub to my windows GitHub program. But I see lots of files that are "deleted". I do not want to see them, how to hide them?

Comment: Here's the repository in question:

https://github.com/parallella/parallella-hw

Comment: Where are you seeing them? In your local repository?

Comment: Yes in local GitHub for windows

Answer (score 1):

When a file is shown as 'deleted' in GitHub for windows, the application is trying to tell you that you've deleted a certain file since you've cloned the repository.

You can't hide the files coming up as 'deleted', as they're changes that need to be committed, however, you can untick the files by clicking the checkbox next to the file name in GitHub for windows, which will stop you committing the deleted files to the Git repository.

In future, if you wish to stop changes that have been made to a specific folder or file type from appearing in GitHub for windows, you can add a .gitignore file to the root directory of the Git repository, with the file extensions and folder names of the files you want to ignore.  More information about gitignore files can be found at https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files